# Change font of theoremref from italic to normal

Tags: fonts, ref

I'm using the `theoremref` package. Some of my sections are numbered with letters, i.e. A, B, C, ... instead of 1, 2, 3, ...

If there is a theorem in, e.g., section A

```
\begin{Theorem}\thlabel{theo} \end{Theorem}
```

then the reference looks like the following:

> \thref{theo} -> Theorem A.1

Now I would like to change the font of A from italic to normal font.

---

A minimal example can be view here (if anything is missing, please write, it's my first question in the forum :-) ): 
https://v1.overleaf.com/21643066jhqtrhnhqmwv

Comment: Welcome to the site.  Know that the official language of this website is English.

Comment: Can you please make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: `\thlabel` and `\thref` are not defined by default.

Comment: In case you prefer to ask your question in German, there is a very similar forum https://texwelt.de/wissen/

Comment: @samcarter See https://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/23481/wie-andere-ich-den-font-bei-theoremref-von-italic-zu-normal. But there is also no MWE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `cleveref` instead of `theoremref`: it's much easier and much better customizable.

```
\documentclass[reqno,12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}   % Silbentrennung
\usepackage{url}              % für URLs und Mailadressen  
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}      % Zeichensatzcodierung
%\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} % Codepage für Eingabe
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}          % Pakete
\usepackage{amsfonts}               % der
\usepackage{amssymb}                    % AMS
\usepackage{array}            % bessere Tabellendarstellung
\usepackage{graphicx}         % Grafik-Einbindung
\usepackage{extarrows}
%\usepackage{a4wide} 
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=alphabetic ,maxnames=99, mincitenames=4,firstinits=true]{biblatex}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[capitalize]{cleveref} %referenzen

\usepackage{enumitem}  %counter enumerate

\pagestyle{plain}             % Zeilennummern unten mittig, kein Header

\numberwithin{equation}{section} %nummerierung der Formeln


\newtheoremstyle{normal}   % name
{11pt}                         % Space above
{11pt}                         % Space below
{\normalfont}                            % Body font
{}                            % Indent amount 1
{\bfseries}                   % Theorem head font
{}                    % Punctuation after theorem head %\newline einsetzen
{.5em}                        % Space after theorem head 2
{}                            % Theorem head spec 
\theoremstyle{linebreak}

\theoremstyle{normal}
\newtheorem{Lemma}{Lemma} \numberwithin{Lemma}{section}
\newtheorem{Bem}[Lemma]{Bemerkung}  
\newtheorem{Def}[Lemma]{Definition}  
\newtheorem{Satz}[Lemma]{Satz}
\newtheorem{Folg}[Lemma]{Folgerung}
\newtheorem{bsp}[Lemma]{Beispiel}
\newtheorem{kor}[Lemma]{Folgerung} 
\newtheorem{Not}[Lemma]{Notation} 
\newtheorem{theo}[Lemma]{Theorem} 
\newtheorem{prob}[Lemma]{Problem} 


\renewcommand{\proofname}{Beweis}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{2} %tiefe Inhaltsverzeichnis

\addbibresource{QuelleDipl.bib}




% erst Nachname, dann Vorname
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{last-first}
% Trenner zwischen den Namen ein Semikolon
\renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}
% Doppelpunkt nach dem letzten Namen
\renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{\addcolon\space}

\renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space} 
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\setstretch {1.5}
\tableofcontents


\newpage
\begin{appendix}
\section{Gebrochen-lineare Transformation von Matrizen}\label{sec:appC}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\Alph{section}.\arabic{equation}}


\begin{Lemma}\label{zusatz}
Sei $P \in  \mathbb C^{p \times p}$. Dann sind folgende Aussagen äquivalent:
\begin{enumerate}
    \item[(i)] $P$ eine ist  Orthoprojektionsmatrix 
    \item[(ii)]$P^{*}=P=P^{2}$
    \item[(iii)] $I_q-P$ ist eine Orthoprojektionsmatrix.
    \end{enumerate}
\end{Lemma}

Einen ausführlichen Beweis von \cref{zusatz} ...


\end{appendix}

\end{document}
```

I commented `latin1` because my system uses UTF-8 and you should too. The `a4wide` package has been deprecated for more than a decade: use `geometry` instead.

As you see, you use the standard `\label` command and `\cref` instead of `\thref`.

[image]

By the way, you should set `\arraystretch` *less* than 1 with `\setstretch{1.5}` or matrices will come up very strange. Use

```
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.66667}
```

instead.

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for your answer (and the additional tipps).

Comment: cleverref is definitely better. It just leads to another problem in my paper. It works as long as I only use Lemma, as soon as I try using Not, Satz or any of the other types i get the error: 'No counter 'N' defined'. Do you know why ?

Comment: @314aja I haven't the issue. I added the same statement, but marked as Satz; I assigned a different label `\label{zusatz+}` and with `\cref{zusatz+}` I get “Satz 1.2”.

Comment: I just copied my whole code into a new file, now i don' get the error either. I don't understand it, but it works :-). So thanks again for your help.